# Save Data Orbeon trigger Mysql

Tags: mysql, forms, orbeon

I have this simple form create in Orbeon:
[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgkbn.png)

I need save on MySQL the data from my form .
I setup the property.local and server.xml and is ok.

Now, If I complete the form, save data on  [table orbeon_form_data (img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0qy2.png).

I create  to move the information from table orbeon_form_data to table "formularioBD":

```
delimiter |
create trigger form_BD before insert 
    on orbeon_form_data 
    for each row begin
        if new.app = 'prueb3' and new.form = 'formularioBD' then
        delete from formularioBD where id_documento = new.document_id;
        if new.deleted = 'N' and new.draft = 'N' then
            insert into formularioBD set id_documento = new.document_id,
            set texto2 = new.app;
            texto3= 
        end if;
    end if;
end;
|
```

I can move the  from table orbeon_form_data to table formularioBD, but the other values not move.
mysql> select * from formularioBD;

```
+------------------------------------------+-------+--------+--------+
| id_documento                             | texto | texto2 | texto3 |
+------------------------------------------+-------+--------+--------+
| 623b3ff9174d0d9fb04e442c1ea786c4ef6f7098 | NULL  | NULL   | NULL   |
| ae86d5f7f39635035c6756c22460c2437d1ae837 |       | NULL   | NULL   |
| b1235abe875adce346eb2e4c2370ab669534c17b |       | NULL   | NULL   |
| a5677881dcda2851d391898b089540b3ef5f308f |       |        | NULL   |
| fa2a25fba728ad5f68bd49c26abcd2f89a61e469 |       | NULL   | NULL   |
| 886955802e5131b201b0e27c8c08560c063087a1 |       | NULL   | NULL   |
| b3cd78d0267547682f191cdf15d8ab6cc97ae12c |       |        |        |
| da1a219c2855390f6e77999572079f466201a830 |       |        |        |
+------------------------------------------+-------+--------+--------+
```

Please Help.!

Regards!

Comment: That `texto3=` in your trigger looks suspicious; is that valid in MySQL, or is your trigger in fact different? I am surprised that the `set texto2 = new.app` doesn't work, and you end up with a `NULL` in your own table. What is the value of `app` in the column you're referencing? Is that value correct, and different than `NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Avernet
I update my trigger and now save the data in my BD form table. Here is the trigger:

```
delimiter |
create trigger trigger_bd before insert on orbeon_form_data for each row begin
    if new.app = 'prueb3' and new.form = 'formularioBD' then
        delete from formularioBD where id_documento = new.document_id;
        if new.deleted = 'N' and new.draft = 'N' then
            insert into formularioBD set id_documento = new.document_id,
                texto = extractValue(new.xml, '/form/section-1/texto'),
        end if;
    end if;
end;
|
```

regards!!